# Executing terminal command with java using variables

Tags: java, shell, terminal, raspberry-pi

It may seems to be a beginner question, but I wrote a bit of code for my raspberry pi and wanted to execute terminal commands with java. So far so good. I got it finally figured out and got it working. But I also wanted my java function to give parametres to the function itself. But I can't figure out how to tell java how to use variables in strings. So heres my code:

```
public static void rcswitch(int code,int unitcode, int onoff) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    String command = "/bin/bash -c 'sudo /home/pi/rcswitch-pi/send code unitcode onoff'";

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    BufferedReader reader = 
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
       String line = "";
       while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line + "\n");
       }
        proc.waitFor();
}
```

It might not be the best option to use but it's working for me. Im currently giving the bash shell the following 'send' command but now I also wanted to use the given parametres. No matter how I write it down it doesn't seem to be working :( The code unitcode and onoff variables should be added after send with one space before each one.

Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You can have more control over the Process, and the ability to execute multiple commands with a ProcessBuilder object. E.G. Some processes will write out important information to STDErr, which you can redirect to STDOut with the process builder.

Comment: Well I tried to do it with a ProcessBuilder object, but how can I get the output? Normally it shows something like command recieved in terminal when I try it out.

Comment: You call Processbuilder.start() which returns the Process object. From there its the same as what youre doing already. Only now, using the ProcessBuilder you could have set things like redirects, or the working directory of the process, and any parameters it needs, etc.

Comment: Another question. The RPi doesn't seem to give an output when I execute the .jar file I created. Not in the console and not in a file. And I don't exactly know why. It seems like the command is not send properly to the terminal.

Comment: I would need to see code. Probably best suited as another question here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a String.format() to construct the command like below:

`String command = String.format("/bin/bash -c 'sudo /home/pi/rcswitch-pi/send %d %d %d'", code, unitcode, onoff);`

Hope this is what you are looking for.